# Image roll over script not working as expected

Tags: javascript, html, dreamweaver

This is how I am calling the JavaScript function in my HTML page:-

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="imagerollover.js"></script>

</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
//Following function should be called at the end of the page:
imagerollover();
</script>
</head>

<body>
.
.
.
```

this is my imagerollover.js:-

```
function imagerollover(){
    
    var allimages=document.getElementsByTagName("img")
    var preloadimages=[]
    for (var i=0; i<allimages.length; i++){
        if (allimages[i].getAttribute("data-over")){ //if image carries "data-over" attribute
            preloadimages.push(new Image()) //preload "over" image
            preloadimages[preloadimages.length-1].src=allimages[i].getAttribute("data-over")
            allimages[i].onmouseover=function(){
                this.src=this.getAttribute("data-over")
            }
            allimages[i].onmouseout=function(){
                this.src=this.getAttribute("data-out")
            }
        } //end if
    } //end for loop
}

//Usage: Call following function at the end of the page:
//imagerollover()
```

Image tags:

```
<img src="knitting1.jpg" 
data-over="knitting2.jpg" 
data-out="knitting1.jpg" 
alt="Logo" width="400px" height="90" align="middle" />
```

Also, both images knitting1.jpg and knitting2.jpg exist in my site's root folder. I don't know what is wrong.

I placed an alert inside imagerollover.js file in the beginning. It is getting called but it is not showing any roll over effect. Why?

Comment: What do your `<img />` tags look like?

Comment: <img src="knitting1.jpg" data-over="knitting2.jpg" data-out="knitting1.jpg" alt="Logo" width="400px" height="90" align="middle" />

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to run this onload - your images tags are not yet available to the script when you execute the function - you are not actually following the instruction of the script which should have been placed at the end of the page or in my suggestion in the onload

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="imagerollover.js"></script>

</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload=function() 
  //Following function should be called at the end of the page OR on window.onload!
  imagerollover();
}
</script>
</head>
```

Comment: yes, window.load event fires when all the images present in document are loaded.